# Additional UTM Parameter and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tags

If I wanted to add an additional UTM parameter outside of the available source, name, medium, term and content, is there a way to get Google Analytics to recognize it?  Specifically, if I added the parameter Stilk, so that the address included "?utm_stilk=*something*", is there a way to have it show up in Google Analytics?

Comment: Have you considered using Custom Dimensions https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use Google Analytics [Custom dimensions & metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en).
Also look at [Custom Reports](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98527) and [Advanced Segments](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108040) those might also help you do what you are looking for.